# Switch Cmd and Control keys for one app only

Tags: keyboard, windows, remote-desktop, switching

I use a mac at work and a home. However, at work I need to log into a Windows virtual machine (using either CoRD or MS RDC) several times each day to do some work. Switching between using control instead of command for common keyboard shortcuts is driving me mad, so I was hoping there was a way to switch these keys only when I am in Windows. That way I wouldn't have to fight my muscle memory for tasks such as cut, copy and paste. (Permanently switching my mac to use a Windows layout is not a solution btw. I like my mac keyboard layout)

I have looked at Ukulele, but it doesn't allow rearranging of modifier keys.

Comment: Many people I know simply connect a PC keyboard via Bluetooth or USB if you don't find a good software solution. Not having the feel of the right keyboard layout is awful to productivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a common issue and it looks like it was answered on superuser side of this web site - Assuming you are happy with a solution for Remote Desktop, this looks to be a duplicate of https://superuser.com/q/263647/76395

Have you had a chance to see if that program will help remap the keys as desired?

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately you may simply need to train your fingers to switch between <kbd>Command</kbd> and <kbd>Control</kbd>. This is what I did years ago, since I go back and forth between Mac and Windows all day long. It still frustrates me on occasion, but I have grown used to it.

However, would there be a way to use **AppleScript** to create a script for toggling **System Preferences: Keyboard: Modifier Keys...** on and off for when you go into your VNC or Remote Desktop session?

[image]

Parenthetically, [Microsoft Windows Remote Desktop for Macintosh](http://www.microsoft.com/mac/downloads?pid=Mactopia_RDC&fid=68346E0D-44D3-4065-99BB-B664B27EE1F0#viewer) tries to handle this for you and gives you a few options for customizing keys and mouse behavior--though not what you are asking for specifically in this case.

[image]